# Excel VBA - make a range not selectable

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to make a range in an Excel file not selectable by the user?
Let's suppose I want cell F5 to be not selectable, so I'd like that if the user is entering data in cell F4 and then hits enter, the next cell to be selected be F6. The same if the user is using the arrow keys to move from an adjacent cell, i.e. from right G5 to left, the selected cell be E5 and not F5.

Comment: Infallibly - no, because VBA can be turned off. However using the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` Sub in your sheet code, you can make it so that if they select a cell within a predefined range, then you can move the ActiveCell to another cell.

Comment: Of course, you could just make some cells unlocked then protect the entire sheet not allowing selection of locked cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'may you need like that code try to do in ***Worksheet_SelectionChange*** event :
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If ActiveCell.Address = "$F$5" Then ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

that may helpful to you